# deserialize null in json to value in c#

Tags: json, api, asp.net-core, patch, json-deserialization

I'm working in project using ASP.net core Api
I have a case which I need to distinguish between undefined variable and null in json .

what I have is that I'm working with Api with put method , so I have json in the body as resource with **2 optional parameter** like that

```
{"bio" : "value , 
  "img" : "value}
```

now in the following case :

```
{"bio :Null}
```

my program in c#**(deserialize from json to c# obj)** will consider bio as null and image as null

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCurrentUser(UserForUpdateOuterDto 
            userForUpdateOuter)
        {
           //some code 

            var userDto = userForUpdateOuter.userForUpdateDto;
            _mapper.Map<UserForUpdateDto ,User>(userDto ,currentUser);
            await _userReposotory.UpdateUser(currentUser); }
```

//auto mapper :

```
 //for update with  Null values .if value is Null then don't map it 
            CreateMap<UserForUpdateDto ,User>().ForAllMembers(x => x.Condition(
                      (src ,dest ,sourceValue) => sourceValue != null));
```

BUT in reality its not the same

so is there away to deserialize null to different value  (I read about that but couldn't found )?
or any other ideas
(I can't use patch coz I'm following spec )

Comment: Are you trying to process a JSON `PATCH` request? If so, you don't need to do this yourself: ASP.NET Core can do this for you automatically. Also, what JSON library are you using? (Newtonsoft.JSON, System.Text.Json, or something else?)

Comment: System.Text.Json 
I cant use patch because specification say use put .. but I want json body that will be converted to object ..to differentiate between parameter that is not defined in json body and its there in the object   so object value is null 
 and json parameter that equal null   so object value is null

Comment: "my program in c#(deserialize from json to c# obj) " -can you show the code you have tried so far and what is the problem, pls?

Comment: And what your code has to do with json you posted? I even don't see any deserialization in your code. " to deserialize null to different value" - to what value?